# How can we share a class in memory inside a FastAPI application

Tags: python-3.x, class, singleton, fastapi, background-task

I need to create a governor class which has a list as a property. Each time a request comes in fastapi a token element gets popped from the list and sent into the background process. Once the background process finishes up it should put this token back into the same list.

**governor.py**

```
        from typing import List
    from datetime import datetime
    from collections import deque
    import threading
    from decouple import AutoConfig
    from fastapi import HTTPException
    from http import HTTPStatus
    
    config = AutoConfig(search_path='.env')
    
    class JobToken:
        """
        Job Token component class with 4 properties
        """
        identifier = str()
        checked_out_at = None
        returned_at = None
        deltatime_seconds = float()
    
    class Governor():
        """
        Singleton class with shared state
        Args:
            Has private variable call __lss which is a LIFO and can't be accessed from outside
        Returns:
            [type]: [description]
        """
        instance = None
        
        #used deque instead of list as deque provides an O(1) time complexity for append and pop operations as compared to list which provides O(n) time complexity. 
        __lss = deque()
        counter = 1
        for i in range(0,int(config('MAX_BACKGROUND_TASKS'))):
                identifier = 'JT_'+str(counter)
                token = JobToken()
                token.identifier = identifier
                __lss.append(token)
                counter+=1
    
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> instance:
            # THis method is used to create only one instance to make it singleton
            if cls.instance is None:
                cls.instance = super().__new__(Governor)
                return cls.instance
            return cls.instance
        
        # Borg Method to share same state between different instances
        __shared_state = {}
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
            
            self._lock = threading.Lock()
        
        def get_token(self) -> JobToken:
            """
            This component first checks the deque length and cleans the token to add checkout time.
            
            Returns:
                JobToken: class object popped out from deck
            """
            with self._lock:
                #This implementation is thread-safe. There is no way for multiple threads to manipulate the token value at the same time, so there's no way that an token value is lost.
                print('---------------------', self.__lss)
                if len(self.__lss)>0:
                    token = self.__lss.pop()
                    token.checked_out_at = datetime.now()
                    token.returned_at = None
                    token.deltaTime_seconds = None
                    return token
                else:
                    raise HTTPException(status_code=HTTPStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
    
                    #TODO: raise hhtp exctption here
        
        def return_token(self, token:JobToken)->None:
            """
            This function puts back token to the deque in order for it to be borrowed again by another process.
            The cleaning doesn't take place here as we need history associated with tokens as well.
    
            Args:
                token ([JobToken]): JobToken object to be returned by methods
            """
            print('------ ',len(self.__lss))
            with self._lock:
                #This implementation is thread-safe. There is no way for multiple threads to manipulate the token value at the same time, so there's no way that an token value is lost.
                if token:
                    token.returned_at = datetime.now()
                    token.deltatime_seconds =  (token.returned_at - token.checked_out_at).total_seconds()
                    self.__lss.append(token)
                else:
                    raise TypeError("Return Token not found")
                
        def inspect_token_list(self)->List[JobToken]:
            """
            This func returns a clone so mutations have no effect on the real bank of tokens
            Returns:
                List[Jobtoken]: []
            """
            return self.__lss.copy()
```

**main.py**

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from lib2to3.pgen2 import token
from typing import Dict
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, HTTPException, Request, status
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
from http import HTTPStatus
import asyncio
import time

from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from governer import Governor

from processors import process_data
from config import XCODE, STAGE_Y, STAGE_Z
#simplest form of tokens

app = FastAPI()

async def run_in_process(fn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(app.state.executor, fn, *args)  

@app.post("/likelySuccess/{guid}", status_code=HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED)
async def executeModel_B(guid:str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    """[summary]
    API route for likelySuccess
    Args:
        guid (str): path parameter to fetch corresponding data
        background_tasks (BackgroundTasks): Task object by fastapi

    Returns:
        [type]: Null Json
    """
    token = Governor().get_token()
    process_identifier = STAGE_Y
    try:
            background_tasks.add_task(run_in_process, process_data, guid, process_identifier, token)
            return {}
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception
```

**proc_module.py**

```
from governor import Governor
def process_data(guid:str, process_identifier:str, token):
   """Some data processing"""
   Governor().return_token(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedisDb for this. It will save tokens in memory, butandcode from any thread can access it

Redis lists can be okay for this task.

Docs: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/tutorial/#lists

```
> rpush mylist token1
(integer) 1
> rpush mylist token2
(integer) 2
> rpop mylist
"token1"
```

It has a very useful python library to send requests from code: https://github.com/redis/redis-py

May another db will be okay too, but Redis is the most simple in you case.